# Is $J(y)= \int_{[1, \infty)} \exp(\frac{-1}{y^2}(x-\frac{1}{y})^2) \, dx$ uniformly convergent on $(0,1)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

Is $$J(y)= \int_{[1, \infty)} \exp \left(\frac{-1}{y^2} \left(x-\frac{1}{y} \right)^2 \right)dx$$ [uniformly convergent](http://planetmath.org/uniformconvergenceofintegral) for $y \in (0,1)$? From what i can see, the Weierstrass M test does not work ...

Comment: What do you mean uniformly convergent? You don't have a sequence of functions, just one function.

Comment: @zhw. http://planetmath.org/uniformconvergenceofintegral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the integrand $f(x,y).$ Let $\epsilon>0.$ If $0<y<\epsilon,$ then

$$\tag 1 \int_{[1, \infty)} f(x,y)\,dx \le \int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y)\,dx = \int_{{\mathbb R}} e^{-x^2/y^2}\,dx =  y\int_{{\mathbb R}} e^{-x^2}\,dx < \epsilon \sqrt {\pi}.$$

Now for $y \in [\epsilon,1]$ and $x\ge 1/\epsilon^2,$

$$\tag 2\frac{1}{y^2}(x-1/y^2)^2 \ge 1\cdot (x-1/y^2)^2 \ge (x-1/\epsilon^2)^2.$$

Choose any $M > 1/\epsilon^2$ such that $\int_M^\infty e^{-(x-1/\epsilon^2)^2}\, dx < \epsilon.$ Then $(2)$ shows$\int_M^\infty f(x,y)\,dx < \epsilon,$ for all $y \in [\epsilon,1].$ Put this together with $(1)$ and we have the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. It can be shown that

$$J(y)={1\over 2}\sqrt{\pi}y\left(1+\Phi({1-y\over y^2})\right)$$

where $\Phi(z)={2\over\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^ze^{-t^2}\,dt$.

Since $\Phi$ is continuous and $\lim_{y\to 0}\Phi({1-y\over y^2})=2$, we see that $J(y)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ and can be extended to a continuous function $\tilde{J}(y)$on $[0,1]$ (because the limit as $y\to 0$ exists and is equal to zero). The result follows because $\tilde{J}(y)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Why does the result follow if $\bar J$ is continuous on $[0,1]?$ Are you using Dini's theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Try [plotting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7Bexp%28%28-5%5E2%29*%28x-5%29%5E2%29%2Cexp%28%28-3%5E2%29*%28x-3%29%5E2%29%2Cexp%28%28-1%5E2%29*%28x-1%29%5E2%29%7D%20) $\exp \left(\frac{-1}{y^2} \left(x-\frac{1}{y} \right)^2 \right)$ as $y \to 0$ and notice that not only it converges to $0$, but mass is also being lost on its way to infinity (imagine the integrand as being a sort of density of a [Gaussian random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with mean $\mu=\frac{1}{y}$ and variance $\sigma^2=\frac{y^2}{2}$ with the normalizing factor $1/\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}$ missing).

That being said, for a fixed $\epsilon$, you can choose a $\delta$ such that $\big|J(y)\big|<\epsilon$ for $y \in (0,\delta)$ and a large enough $M$ such that $\bigg|\int_{[M, \infty)} \exp \left(\frac{-1}{y^2} \left(x-\frac{1}{y} \right)^2 \right)dx\bigg|<\epsilon$ for $y \in [\delta,1)$ since $y \in [\delta,1)$ implies that the 'means of the densities' are bounded $(\mu \in (1,1/\delta])$ and there is a compact where nearly all the mass is concentrated.